# Can't add any new Angular Module

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, jhipster

In Jhipster v3.9.1,
i tried add module to my projet, but i can't .
For example, i want to add this module http://hakib.github.io/MassAutocomplete/
so i run bower install angular-mass-autocomplete --save
after i run gulp inject:vendor and gulp inject:dep

So the index.html is refreshed now and the module is there

So when i want to use it, i tried to add the .$inject=[] array , it didn't work, i tried use it next to module, it didn't work too ! .module('moduleName', ['mass-autocomplete'])

It gives me always this error :
angular.js:13920 Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: mass-autocompleteProvider <- mass-autocomplete <- ControllerName

Can't we use a bower module or NPM module ??

Thank you

Comment: Can you provide the code of injection?

Answer (score 0):

The first javascript example on linked page shows the injection

> var app = angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize', 'MassAutoComplete']);

when in your question you do it like

> .module('moduleName', ['mass-autocomplete'])

change 'mass-autocomplete' to 'MassAutoComplete' and it should work - unless you didn't included the JS library in your output JS

Comment: Same problem man :)
 angular
        .module('ModuleNameHere',['ngSanitize', 'MassAutoComplete'])

Error : jquery.js:3793 Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ModuleNameHere due to: Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateProvider

Comment: Well it is not the same error, you have other problem when you inject `$state`

Comment: Indeed, it's not the same problem :) I mean the problem persist :) Do you have idea about this problem ? thanks

Comment: It's normal you removed completely the required modules, so of course you no longer inject ui-router which provides $state, see the basic list of modules JHipster requires on a sample rpoject:  https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/app/app.module.js